# Microsoft OneDrive client setting lastModifiedDateTime incorrectly

Tags: office365, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having some problems with the lastModifiedDateTime that's being set by the Microsoft OneDrive web and native clients when uploading a new file.

*Note that the following tests were performed on 26th August 2016 - notice the correct createdDateTime in the examples below.*

When uploading a new file from the OneDrive **web client**, it assigns a random lastModifiedDateTime value from 2012 - but with the correct time:

[image: onedrive web client]

When uploading a new file from the OneDrive **native client**, it sets the lastModifiedDateTime value as tomorrow - and with an incorrect time value:

[image: onedrive native client]

However, when uploading a new file via a POST to the Graph API, it sets the correct lastModifiedDateTime:

[image: graph api]

It's also worth noting that when any subsequent update is made to an already existing file in OneDrive through the web or native clients, it does correctly set the new lastModifiedDateTime. So this issue only appears to be present when  uploading a new file for the first time.

Is there a plan for Microsoft to fix these bugs in the OneDrive web and native clients?

Comment: What request are you making in the first two examples? Since you're getting the "remoteItem" property on those responses, it seems like you aren't accessing the item directly from the drive, but perhaps through something like /sharedWithMe or /recent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this and it doesn't seem like it's an issue anymore. lastModifiedDateTime is now something sensible.